# Product of more than two subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $A_1,A_2,...,A_n$ be subgroups of $G$ and $H=A_1A_2...A_n$.

Is there any sufficient and necessary condition for $H$ to be subgroup ?

When $n=2$, $H$ is a subgroup if and only if $A_1A_2=A_2A_1$. I do not know if there is any generalization of this principle ?

**Note:** if necessary you may assume $G$ is finite.

**Edit:** This question seems to be already asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191690/when-is-the-product-of-n-subgroups-a-subgroup) with not accepted answer.

Comment: This was asked before [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191690/when-is-the-product-of-n-subgroups-a-subgroup).

Comment: $H$ is a subgroup if and only if $H^2 = H$ and $H^{-1} = H$, hence one (easy/trivial) sufficent and necessary condition is "$A_1 A_2 \cdots A_n = A_n \cdots A_2 A_1$ and $A_1 A_2 \cdots A_n A_1 A_2 \cdots A_n = A_1 A_2 \cdots A_n$". In the case $n = 2$ the second condition follows from the first, but not when $n > 2$

Comment: @spin: if we assume that $G$ is finite, can we remove the second condition ?

Comment: @mesel: If you mean the condition $H^{-1} = H$, yes

Comment: yeah, that is what I mean.